# Different behaviour list initialization when specifying constructor

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17

I have code like this for example :

```
class A {
public:
    int x;

    A() {
        std::cout << "Constructor Called !" << std::endl;
    }
    A(int y):x(y) {
        std::cout << "Constructor Param Called !" << std::endl;
    }

    A(const A& copy) {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor Called !" << std::endl;
    }
}

class B {
public:
    A value;
    //B(const A& val) : value(val){}
}

int main(){
    B b { A(22)};
}
```

If i comment out the B constructor the output is just "Constructor Param Called", but if i uncomment B constructor the output would be "Constructor Param Called" & "Copy Constructor Called". My questions :

1. Why is the output different if i commented out the constructor ? (I've read about aggregate class & aggregate initialization, is this it ?)
2. What's the difference between [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) & [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) ?

Comment: On a side note: your `A` default constructor and copy constructor are not initializing the `x` member, so in the cases where a `B` object is default-constructed without an `A` input value, or if a `B` object is constructed with an `A` input value and the `B` constructor is uncommented, then the value of `B.value.x` will be *indeterminate* after construction, which will lead to *undefined behavior* if `B.value.x` is ever read from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh you're right, at first I thought it would just initialize to 0 by default or something. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you remove the user-provided constructor for `B`, `B` becomes an aggregate. So aggregate-initialization is performed where each element of the class is copy-initialized from the elements of the initializer list. Since `A(22)` is a prvalue of the same class as `B`'s element, copy-elision takes place where the value is stored directly into the object without any calls to the copy-constructor. This is new as of C++17.

When you declare the constructor for `B`, it is no longer an aggregate, so constructors are considered when you're doing an initialization.

Direct-intialization just means there is no `=` sign when you're initializing an object. Aggregate-initialization is what takes place when you're initializing an aggregate, and you can take a look at the [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Definitions) on cppreference for that.